# mysql group_concat for left and right table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I am using `group_concat` function to aggregate few movements of a product which already done for right table `(stockout)` with `left join`. MySQL code is below-

```
SELECT
    p.serialno AS SISN,
    p.in_quantity AS INQTY, 
    SUM(IFNULL(s.out_quantity, '0')) AS OUTQTY,
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(
                COALESCE(IFNULL(s.out_quantity,'0'), ''),'|'
            )
        ) details
FROM stockin p LEFT JOIN stockout s 
    ON p.serialno = s.serialno
    WHERE p.productid = 'TF00123'
GROUP BY p.stockin_id, p.serialno, s.serialno
```

Output as follows-

```
+------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+
| SISN | INQTY | OUTQTY | details                        |
+------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+
| AAA1 |   500 |    740 | 300|,100|,50|,50|,20|,20|,200| |
| AAA2 |   500 |      0 | 0|                             |
| AAA3 |     1 |      3 | 1|,1|,1|                       |
| AAA3 |     1 |      3 | 1|,1|,1|                       |
| AAA1 |   200 |    740 | 300|,100|,50|,50|,20|,20|,200| |
| AAA3 |     1 |      3 | 1|,1|,1|                       |
| AAA1 |   100 |    740 | 300|,100|,50|,50|,20|,20|,200| |
+------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I want to `group_concat` of left table quantities in another column like details if p.serialno is same.
Please check the output if i do manually-

```
+------+-------+------------------+--------+--------------------------------+
| SISN | INQTY | details          | OUTQTY | details                        |
+------+-------+------------------+--------+--------------------------------+
| AAA1 |   800 | 500|,200|,100|   |    740 | 300|,100|,50|,50|,20|,20|,200| |
| AAA2 |   500 | 0|               |      0 | 0|                             |
| AAA3 |     3 | 1|,1|,1|         |      3 | 1|,1|,1|                       |
+------+-------+------------------+--------+--------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
 GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(
                COALESCE(IFNULL(p.out_quantity,'0'), ''),'|'
            )
        ) details1
```

Like this

```
SELECT
    p.serialno AS SISN, 
    p.in_quantity AS INQTY, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(
                COALESCE(IFNULL(p.out_quantity,'0'), ''),'|'
            )
        ) details1
    SUM(IFNULL(s.out_quantity, '0')) AS OUTQTY,
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(
                COALESCE(IFNULL(s.out_quantity,'0'), ''),'|'
            )
        ) details
FROM stockin p LEFT JOIN stockout s 
    ON p.serialno = s.serialno
    WHERE p.productid = 'TF00123'
GROUP BY p.stockin_id, p.serialno, s.serialno
```